# inputCheckbox Label is not displaying?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am displaying 2 checkbox and I want to display name of the 2 checkbox as Yes and No, but it is not displaying.

[image: Inputcheckbox]

and here is code:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<apex:pageBlock>
2. Have there been any significant changes in employment or income or do?<br></br>
<apex:inputCheckbox label="yes"/>
<apex:inputCheckbox /><br></br>
3. Have there been any significant changes in your savings investment future?<br></br>
<apex:inputCheckbox />
<apex:inputCheckbox /><br></br>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The label of checkbox wouldn't display unless it is in an `<apex:pageBlockSection>`. Otherwise, you will have to state the label manually.

Comment: I have written inside <apex:pageBlock> but still not displaying.

Comment: @avidForce My fault. Should be `<apex:pageBlockSection>`. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Another possibile solution, that does not require the `<apex:pageBlockSection>`, is the `<apex:outputLabel>`:

```
<apex:form id="myform">
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!bMyValue}" id="MyCheckbox"/>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Checkbox label" for="MyCheckbox"/>
</apex:form>
```